# hook_views_pre_execute not working

Tags: views

I want to alter the view query before rendering the view, so I use the hook_views_pre_execute. I want to add an 'WHERE' 'AND' condition clause to the query. So here is my code :

```
MYMODULE_views_pre_execute(&$view) {
    // some code here to get my node id to exclude
    $view->query->add_where('1', 'node.nid', $nid_exclude, '!=');
}
```

but it seems to me the hook not working, or I did mistake to the `add_where`function?

UPDATE : The hook is executed but the view is not modified.

Comment: Does "not working" mean that the hook never executes, or that the View does not modify it's behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To alter query you should use [hook_views_query_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7)

Sample Code using `hook_views_query_alter` :

```
function MODULE_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query){
switch($view -> name){
    case 'products':
        if($view->current_display == 'block_1'){
            $nids = get_nid();
            $nids = !empty($nids) ? $nids : array(0);
            $query->where[1]['conditions'][2]['value'] = $nids;
            $query->where[1]['conditions'][2]['operator'] = 'IN';
        }
            break;
  }
}
```